# C # word to insert a shape to the table the specified cell

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

Excuse me, how to insert in the word header table shape to the designated cell?
The following code doesn't work, the two shapes can only in the first cell.

```
Range oCell1 = newTable.Cell(1, 1).Range;
float top1 = oWord.Selection.get_Information(WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage);
float left1 = oWord.Selection.get_Information(WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage);
newTable.Cell(1, 1).VerticalAlignment = WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalBottom;
newTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape1 = oDoc.Shapes.AddShape(shapeId, left1, top1 , oWord.CentimetersToPoints(float.Parse("1.1")), oWord.CentimetersToPoints(float.Parse("0.5")), oCell1);
Range oCell2 = newTable.Cell(1, 3).Range;
float top2 = oWord.Selection.get_Information(WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage);
float left2 = oWord.Selection.get_Information(WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape2 = oDoc.Shapes.AddShape(shapeId, left2, top2 , oWord.CentimetersToPoints(float.Parse("1.1")), oWord.CentimetersToPoints(float.Parse("0.5")), oCell2);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ0NF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word sometimes does not place things appropriately. One way you can get around it is to make it elsewhere and then copy/paste to the desired location.

```
Selection sel = doc.Application.Selection;
Table newTable = sel.Tables[1];
Cell cell_1 = newTable.Cell(1, 1);
Range oCell1 = cell_1.Range;
float top1 = sel.get_Information(WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage);
float left1 = sel.get_Information(WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage);
cell_1.VerticalAlignment = WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalBottom;
cell_1.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
Interop.Shape shape1 = doc.Shapes.AddShape((int)MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeCube,
    left1, top1, app.CentimetersToPoints(float.Parse("1.1")),
    app.CentimetersToPoints(float.Parse("0.5")), oCell1);
shape1.ConvertToInlineShape();
oCell1.Copy();

Range oCell2 = newTable.Cell(1, 3).Range;
oCell2.Select();
oCell2.Paste();
```